# Understanding full text index of Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, lucene, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

On the latest version of Neo4j, I'm trying to understand how a text search can be done. I've read the manual on creating [full text indexes](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/indexing-create-advanced.html) but please help me with the following questions:

1. When I want to do partial text matches, I would create a fulltext index on that property. Let's say: text in a webpage. When I create a fulltext index, is that the same as building an inverted index?
2. In Neo4j, how are the results returned: when I do a partial match, does it return all the matching content? Is there any form of ranking on the returned result set?
3. Is the full text index configurable to allow a different ranking function?

Any help is much appreciated!